# Android SimpleCursorAdaptor Image ViewBinder

Tags: android

I am using Gridview with ImageView and TextView. I am using SimpleCursorAdapter to display the data from SQLite database. I am able to display the data in TextView from database but not the Images in ImageView. My Image path is stored in one of the fields in the database. I need code for both options like storing images on SD_CARD and also in res drawable folder and read the Image path from database. Any help is really appreciated. I have searched so much but no luck. Thanks in advance. I am new to android and please use my below code and modify it. e.g ImageName are test1.png, test2.png, test3.png, , , ,test98.png etc. Have 100 image names in the database and associated data in Fiedl_2.

case 3:

mCursor = DemoApplication.getDbAdapter().getData(DemoApplication.Field_1, DemoApplication.Field_2, DemoApplication.Fiedl_3);

startManagingCursor(mCursor);
String[] from = new String[] {"ImageName", "Field_4", "_id"};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.pic, R.id.text1};
                                        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_with_image, mCursor, from, to)

//gv is gridview and setting up two columns

gv.setNumColumns(2);

gv.setAdapter(adapter);

gv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly it seems like you need to extend `SimpleCursorAdapter`or possibly `CursorAdapter`. See this discussion:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/android-custom-cursoradapter-design

You should look to override the `newView()` and `bindView()` methods.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I have gridview and in that first column is ImageView and Second column is TextView. I am able to display the data from database in second column which is TextView. I need to display the Images in first column which is ImageView. All the Image names are stored in the database and actual images are on SD_Card or res drawable folder.